# Deployment zend framework 2 to hosting server?

Tags: zend-framework, zend-framework2

the questions that i going to ask may sound very silly for ZF developer but i really need help on this. I just start ZF2 recently and followed the tutorial http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/user-guide/overview.html to create skeleton application.

Now i trying to put the skeleton application to my hosting server(FYI, i'm using hostgator shared hosting). However, I have no idea on how do this and i heard that hostgator's shared hosting do not allow installation for zend framework.

I oso do heard that zend framework do not need installation but only copy the Zend library folder([Installing Zend Framework 2 Without Root Access?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12395073/installing-zend-framework-2-without-root-access)). My questions are as following:

1. How to put my local skeleton application to the hosting server?
2. Is that we can just need to copy the zend library to the server to get started? because i heard copy of zend library only applicable to zf1 but not zf2
3. For zf2, do we really need to start with skeleton application? if not, what's other methods can i use to build zend app?

Sorry for the silly questions but i really have no experience on zend framework. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Since you've followed the user-manual, all the files that ZF2 needs are within your `$projectDir`.

This means, all you have to do is to copy all files of your `$projectDir` onto your hosting Server and you're almost done. The only thing that really needs to be done after that point is to set up your domain / subdomain to route into the `/public`-folder of your `$projectDir`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I will try it out. However, may I know how to set up my domain/subdomain route into my public/ folder?

Comment: I'm no server guy ;) Easiest would be to ask your hosting provider ;)

Comment: It works! I don't know it was so simple and I'm so silly to dunno that. Thank you very much!